# How can I number my references like [1.1], [1.2]...[1.n], instead of [1], [2]...[n], depending on the chapter they are allocated in?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, natbib

I want to number my references like: [1.1], [1.2]...[1.n] for chapter 1, [2.1], [2.2]...[2.n] for chapter 2 etc. How can I do that with natbib?

```
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
Bla bla bla \cite{Ref1}

\renewcommand\bibsection{\section{\refname}}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you _do_ need to use both `natbib` and `chapterbib`?

Comment: I am not sure. Probably not. Do you know how to achieve what I ask with either of these?

Comment: `chapterbib` has a `\CitationPrefix{\thechapter.}` usage. It works for per chapter bibliography only. For `natbib` with `numbers` citing style, you can use `\renewcommand*\citenumfont[1]{\thechapter.#1}`.